# Camera media source with media foundation - MS Sample code doesn't compile with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, ms-media-foundation

I tried compiling [this sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317912(v=vs.85).aspx) with Visual Studio 2013 for Win64 (on Windows 8.1).
I included mfapi.h and mfidl.h. However it gets compilation errors with identifiers not found for example:

MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE
MFEnumDeviceSources

I googled, and saw mention of these features being windows 7+ specific and of a VS "platform toolset" property which is required to enable them - but this property doesn't seem to exist in VS 2013.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you have the symbol ``_WIN32_WINNT`` set to for your project?

Comment: The project is generated by Unreal Engine 4  UnrealBuildTool, which seems to be setting it to 0x0600

Comment: 0x600 seems to be Windows Vista so I guess that explains it. Thx. For anyone using UE-4 see Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealBuildTool/Windows/UEBuildWindows.cs

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the C++ project a Win32 Project, not a Store App project type. If you look at mfidl.h there is a compile flag that disables all the Media Foundation DEVSOURCE attributes when it is not a desktop application, i.e., WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP) is only true when the project type is Win32, not Windows 8.1.